# iPhone connected via USB not appearing in OS X Safari 'Develop' menu after upgrading to iOS 7

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, mobile-safari, web-inspector

I have been using the Web Inspector in Safari (Mac) to debug mobile web apps on my iPhone on iOS 6. After upgrading to iOS 7 my iPhone no longer appears in the 'Develop' menu of Safari on my Mac.

I'm currently using an iPhone 4S, OS X 10.8.5, and the latest Safari.

I have checked that 'Web Inspector' in enabled in Advanced Safari settings on the iPhone. I have also tried restarting the device, Safari, and reconnecting the cable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must install Safari 6.1 for having access to iOS7 devices through WebInspector. Safari 6.1 is available on Apple's developer website.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that was available. For anybody else with the same question, the download is available at https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: Tried installing 6.1 also with 6.2. Still doesn't shows. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

WebKit Nightly Builds is an alternative if you don't have access to the download links of Safari 6.1 preview.

http://nightly.webkit.org/

Comment: The reason I ended up on this page is because the WebKit Nightly Build wasn't detecting it either. Weird.

Comment: Having the same issue after upgrading to the newest version. Try installing a previous build from [http://nightly.webkit.org/builds/trunk/mac/1]. I downgraded to r156224, and it works for me.